# LWC Simple Calculator

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I am trying to create a simple calculator : below are the codes :
When i am adding it to my lightning page i am getting the Error:

HTML:

```
<template>
 <lightning-card title="Simple Calculator" icon-name="Standard:formula">
   <lightning-layout multiple-rows>

     <lightning-layout-item size="12" padding="around-medium">
       <lightning-input type="number" name="firstNumber"></lightning-input>
    </lightning-layout-item>

   <lightning-layout-item size="12" padding="around-medium">
    <lightning-input type="number" name="secondNumber"></lightning-input>
   </lightning-layout-item>

   <lightning-layout-item padding="around-medium">
   <lightning-button-group>
       <lightning-button label="Add" icon-name="Utility:add" icon-position="right"></lightning-button>
       <lightning-button label="Substract" icon-name="Utility:dash" icon-position="right"></lightning-button>
       <lightning-button label="Multiply" icon-name="Utility:close" icon-position="right"></lightning-button>
       <lightning-button label="Divide"  icon-name="Utility:magicwand" icon-position="right"></lightning-button>
   </lightning-button-group>
   </lightning-layout-item>


   <lightning-layout-item size="12" padding="around-medium">
       <lightning-formatted-text></lightning-formatted-text>
   </lightning-layout-item>

   </lightning-layout>
 </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Meta File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <description>Simple Calculator App build With LWC</description>
    <targets>
      <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
      <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
      <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
  </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Error:

```
Unknown token: 'undefined'. Are you missing a tokens file or declaration?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with the icon-name="Standard:formula". S needs to be small not CAPS, similarly for Utility u needs to be small. This is will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the **label** attribute is required when using a `lightning-input` element.
To hide the babel, add **variant="label-hidden"** to your lightning elements.
Here is a [playground link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/f1kzluOU7/3/edit) for you.
Also use **utility** instead of Utility in your icon-name attributes